# Characters counting and subletting specific patterns

Tags: r

I have a list of data.frames (d) that looks like this:

> ```
> $ 1  :'data.frame':   1 obs. of  2 variables:     
> ..$ index: int 2
> ```
>
> ..$ V1   : Factor w/ 125 levels "cgtsloqasmlkjybjlo,..:"
>
> ```
>   $ 2  :'data.frame': 1 obs. of  2 variables:  
> ..$ index: int 2
>  ..$ V1   : Factor w/ 125 levels "ponlohlofdctlo,..:"
> ```

and so on for 1000 data.frames. I have to count the number of unique letters occurring in  "cgtsloqasmlkjybjlo,..:" as well as in  "ponlohlofdctlo,..:"  and in the other 1000 data.frames. 
I tried a stupid function, but I'm not an expert so it is wrong also because it does not work:

Anyway I tried to split (but it does not work..):

> ```
>  chars = sapply(d, function(x) strsplit(as.character(d),""))
> ```

In addiction, I have to count the number of occurrences of "lo" in "cgtsloqasmlkjybjlo,..:" as well as in "ponlohlofdctlo,..:" and in the other 1000.

Edit: the desired output will be a data.frame:

> ```
>         Seq           length(unique_letters)   lo_occurrences
>  cgtsloqasmlkjybjlo           13                       2      
>    ponlohlofdctlo             9                        3     
>    ..............           ............         ............    
>
>
>  dput output: 
>   dput(d[1:3])
> ```
>
> structure(list(`1` = structure(1000L, .Label = c("jhgfilsouilohgucaksfiaaknajdauloadbayrzjdhad", "fjkhqurtglowqgbdahhmolovdethabvfdalo", "....", "V1"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("1", "2", "3"))

Comment: It is hard (for me, at least) to understand exactly what you are looking for. Could you show an abbreviated form of your list of data frames using `dput()` etc, as described in [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: I tried, but it seems to be impossible due to the dimension of the list. R crashed..

Comment: Can you make up a simple & contrived example, perhaps w/ just 2 data frames, & the output you would want to get from the example?

Comment: Just the first (say) 3 items of the list would be enough. Try `dput(d[1:3])`. If the data frames themselves are big, you might need to create a sample list that contains shortened versions of those data frames.

Comment: edited with dput output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way is this:

```
#simulating your list; I got an error trying to use your dput
d <- list(data.frame(index = 2, V1 = "cgtsloqasmlkjybjlo"), 
      data.frame(index = 2, V1 = "ponlohlofdctlo"))
d
#[[1]]
#  index                 V1
#1     2 cgtsloqasmlkjybjlo

#[[2]]
#  index             V1
#1     2 ponlohlofdctlo

res <- do.call(rbind, lapply(d, function(x) data.frame(seq = as.character(x$V1), 
       length_uniques = length(unique(unlist(strsplit(as.character(x$V1), "")))), 
               lo_counts = length(unlist(gregexpr("lo", as.character(x$V1)))))))
res
#                 seq length_uniques lo_counts
#1 cgtsloqasmlkjybjlo             13         2
#2     ponlohlofdctlo              9         3
```